# How can I use ios mode alert box after setting the entire app to use md mode

Tags: angular, ionic2

After I have set my app to run in ‘md’ mode using

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
  mode: 'md'
}, {}),
```

Is it still possible to use the ios version of alert box?

If yes, how can we do that?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It is as easy as:

```
alert.setMode("ios");
```

where "alert" is an instance of "AlertController"